# PowerShell.WindowsForms.Change ListBox via SelectedItemChanged in ComboBox

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, combobox, selecteditemchanged

I went on to develop the script. Now the goal is this: When selecting a department in ListBoxDepartments, the SubDepartments in ListBoxSubDepartments should be displayed. I did it according to the principle mentioned above. But it doesn't work out. Or is there a need for a different approach? Please point to the code how to implement it?

*>>If that is what you want, then you need to also have a SelectedItemChanged event declared on the listbox and when that fires, fill that second listbox with the sub departments. * - I already have SelectedItemChanged on the Deparments ListBox.

Look below in the code:

```
<#----======= ComboBox Organization =======----#>

$ComboBoxOrganization = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBoxOrganization.Sorted = $true
foreach($org in $HashOrganizations.Keys){ 
$ComboBoxOrganization.Items.Add($org)
}
$ComboBoxOrganization.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,30)
$ComboBoxOrganization.SelectedIndex = 0
$ComboBoxOrganization.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $listBoxDepartments.BeginUpdate()
    $listBoxDepartments.Items.Clear()
      foreach ($dept in $HashOrganizations[$this.SelectedItem]) {  
        [void]$listBoxDepartments.Items.Add($dept)
    }
    $listBoxDepartments.EndUpdate()
})
$main_form.Controls.Add($ComboBoxOrganization)

<#----======= ComboBox Organization =======----#>
<#----======= ListBox Departments =======----#>

$listBoxDepartments = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBoxDepartments.Location = '180,75'
$listBoxDepartments.Size = '400,100'
$listBoxDepartments.Sorted   = $true
foreach ($dept in $HashOrganizations[$ComboBoxOrganization.SelectedItem]) {  
    [void]$listBoxDepartments.Items.Add($dept)
}
$**listBoxDepartments.Add_SelectedIndexChanged**({
    $listBoxSubDepartments.BeginUpdate()
    $listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Clear()
        foreach($SubDep in $hashCOMPANY1[$this.SelectedItem]) {
            [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
    }
})
$main_form.Controls.Add($listBoxDepartments)


<#----======= ListBox Departments =======----#>
<#----======= ListBox SubDepartments =======----#>

$listBoxSubDepartments = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBoxSubDepartments.Location = '180,195'
$listBoxSubDepartments.Size = '400,100'
$listBoxSubDepartments.Sorted   = $true
foreach ($SubDep in $hashCOMPANY1[$listBoxDepartments.SelectedItem]) {  
    [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
}
$main_form.Controls.Add($listBoxSubDepartments)

<#----======= ListBox SubDepartments =======----#>

$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

If you mean something difference from my code, please show in the code when i should paste this event "SelectedItemChanged"?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm seeing lots of errors.  First you need to add at beginning of code "using assembly System.Windows.Forms"  Second the variable $HashOrganizations is empty which creates a lot of errors.  Are you seeing any error when you run the code?

Comment: Oh! Yes! System.Windows.Forms - already added, i just not put in this. And Variable  $HashOrganizations to anounced in all code and have a values

Comment: I just put this a part of code: 
$HashOrganizations  = @{
        
        'COMPANY-4' = 'Department 1','Department 2','Department 3'
        'COMPANY-3' = 'Department 4','Department 5','Department 6'
        'COMPANY-2' = 'Department 7','Department 8','Department 9'
        'COMPANY-1' = 'Department 10','Department 11','Department 12'
}

$hashCOMPANY1 = @{
    
        'Department 10' = 'SubDep-1','SubDep-2','SubDep-3','SubDep-4'
        'Department 11' = 'SubDep-5','SubDep-6','SubDep-7','SubDep-8'
        'Department 12' = 'SubDep-9','SubDep-10','SubDep-11','SubDep-12'

}

Comment: In this part of the code, i have some error:

Indexing operation failed, array index is calculated as NULL.
line:149 character:21
+ ... oreach ($SubDep in $hashCOMPANY1[$listBoxDepartments.SelectedItem]) {
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Comment: You $hashOrganization definitions has errors.  You need to fix.

Comment: I don't understand, what the error has $hashOrganization - can You show me this error?

Comment: After running code just type in PS :  $HashOrganizations

Comment: You forgot to put `$listBoxSubDepartmentsEndUpdate()` as last line of the `SelectedIndexChanged()` event handler on the $listBoxDepartments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for explaining in a comment, but what you need is a second Hashtable with the sub departments listed for the various departments.

So apart from having

```
$hashOrganizations = @{
    'COMPANY-1' = 'Department 1','Department 2','Department 3','Department 4'
    'COMPANY-2' = 'Department 5','Department 6','Department 7'
}
```

You need a similar Hashtable for the sub departments:

```
$hashSubDepartments = @{
    'Department 1' = 'SubDept1-1','SubDept1-2','SubDept1-3','SubDept1-4'
    'Department 2' = 'SubDept2-1','SubDept2-2'
    'Department 3' = 'SubDept3-1','SubDept3-2','SubDept3-3'
    'Department 4' = 'SubDept4-1','SubDept4-2','SubDept4-3'
    # etcetera
}
```

Then, as commented you need to add `$listBoxSubDepartments.EndUpdate()` method in the Add_SelectedIndexChanged event handler so the new content will be shown:

```
$listBoxDepartments.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $listBoxSubDepartments.BeginUpdate()
    $listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Clear()
    foreach($SubDep in $hashSubDepartments[$this.SelectedItem]) {
        [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
    }
    $listBoxSubDepartments.EndUpdate()
})
```

If need be (when the various companies have equally named departments and/or sub departments, combine the company name with the department name in the `$hashSubDepartments` keys, like:

```
$hashSubDepartments = @{
    'COMPANY-1|Department 1' = 'SubDept1-1','SubDept1-2','SubDept1-3','SubDept1-4'
    'COMPANY-2|Department 1' = 'SubDept1-1','SubDept1-2','SubDept1-3','SubDept1-4'
    'COMPANY-1|Department 2' = 'SubDept2-1','SubDept2-2'
    'COMPANY-2|Department 2' = 'SubDept2-1','SubDept2-2','SubDept1-3'
    'COMPANY-1|Department 3' = 'SubDept3-1','SubDept3-2','SubDept3-3'
    'COMPANY-2|Department 3' = 'SubDept3-1','SubDept3-2'
    'COMPANY-1|Department 4' = 'SubDept4-1','SubDept4-2','SubDept4-3'
    'COMPANY-2|Department 4' = 'SubDept4-1','SubDept4-2','SubDept4-3'
    # etcetera
}
```

The event code would then read

```
$listBoxDepartments.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $listBoxSubDepartments.BeginUpdate()
    $listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Clear()
    $keyName = '{0}|{1}' -f $ComboBoxOrganization.SelectedItem, $this.SelectedItem
    foreach($SubDep in $hashSubDepartments[$keyName]) {
        [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
    }
    $listBoxSubDepartments.EndUpdate()
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. In my code just missed this variable $listBoxSubDepartments.EndUpdate() in code block $listBoxDepartments.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({...})

Comment: @CatcherRem Yep, thought as much ;). You can do without `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()`, but then the screen will try to refresh on each addition which becomes slow and tiresome for the user

Comment: It works in principle. There is a small problem, there is a double data. For example. The companies COMPANY1 and COMPANY2 have an Accounting Department (in both companies it is called the same) But they have different sub-departments. With this code logic, it turns out that all subdepartments from the accounting departments of the two companies fall into the listboxSubDepartments.

Comment: ...Example: Accounting COMPANY1 has subdepartments Subdepartment1 and Subdepartment2. Accounting COMPANY2 has subdepartments Subdepartment1 and Subdepartment3. By selecting COMPANY1 or COMPANY2 and Department Accounting in listboxsubdepartment I get the data: Subdepartment1, Subdepartment1, Subdepartment2, subdepartment3.

How can change the double data?

Comment: Part of code:

$listBoxDepartments = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBoxDepartments.Location = '180,75'
$listBoxDepartments.Size = '400,100'
$listBoxDepartments.Sorted   = $true
foreach ($dept in $hash[$ComboBoxOrganization.SelectedItem]) {  
    [void]$listBoxDepartments.Items.Add($dept)
}

Comment: ...

$listBoxDepartments.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $listBoxSubDepartments.BeginUpdate()
    $listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Clear()
        foreach($SubDep in $hashCOMPANY1[$this.SelectedItem]) {
            [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
    }
        foreach($SubDep in $hashCOMPANY2[$this.SelectedItem]) {
            [void]$listBoxSubDepartments.Items.Add($SubDep)
    }
    $listBoxSubDepartments.EndUpdate()
})
$main_form.Controls.Add($listBoxDepartments)

Comment: @CatcherRem I also gave you code how to combine the company name with the main department so you can store the subdepartments specific for each organization inside one Hashtable. I would use that instead of hashes-per-company